# SwiftUI Textfield Controls, Errors on Exit

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, macos-catalina

SwiftUI Textfield Controls, Errors on Exit

I'm receiving multiple console chatter items when simply moving from textfield to
textfield in SwiftUI. When adding a new record or editing an existing one, if I
hit the keyboard return key (running on a device) I receive no warnings or errors. If
I simply tap another textfield (without using the return key) I get all this chatter.

Start:
19:45:46.969678-0700 ToDo[688:477250] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "",
    "",
    "",
    ""
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in  may also be helpful.
2019-08-29 19:45:46.995748-0700 ToDo[688:477250] [Snapshotting] Snapshotting a view (0x14fe87ff0, _UIReplicantView) that has not been rendered at least once requires afterScreenUpdates:YES.
End:

In both cases the data is saved correctly. I am storing the data in Core Data.iOS 13.1, Xcode 11M392r - website says Beta 7, my Xcode says this build is Beta 6, Catalina19A546d.

Here's the view:

```
struct AddNewToDo: View {

@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

@State private var updatedTitle: String = "No Title"
@State private var updatedFirstName: String = "No Title"
@State private var updatedLastName: String = "No Title"
@State private var updatedDate: Date = Date()
@State private var updatedDateString: String = "July 2019"

var body: some View {

    VStack {

        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("ToDo Title:")
                .padding(.leading, 5)
                .font(.headline)
            TextField("Enter a Title", text: $updatedTitle)
                .onAppear {
                    self.updatedTitle = ""
            }
            .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
        }
        .padding(10)

        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("First Name:")
                .padding(.leading, 5)
                .font(.headline)
            TextField("Enter First Name", text: $updatedFirstName)
                .onAppear {
                    self.updatedFirstName = ""
            }
            .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())

        }
        .padding(10)

        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Last Name:")
                .padding(.leading, 5)
                .font(.headline)
            TextField("Enter Last Name", text: $updatedLastName)
                .onAppear {
                    self.updatedLastName = ""
                }
            .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
        }
        .padding(10)

        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Created Date:")
                .padding(.leading, 5)
                .font(.headline)
            TextField("Enter a date", text: $updatedDateString)
                .onAppear {
                    let formatter = DateFormatter()
                    formatter.timeZone = .current
                    formatter.dateFormat = "M-d-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
                    let myString = formatter.string(from: Date())
                    //let myCoreDataString = formatter.string(from: self.toDoItem.createdAt!)
                    //print(myString)
                    //print("myCoredataString is \(myCoreDataString)")
                    self.updatedDateString = myString
                   }
            .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
        }
        .padding(10)

        VStack {
            Button(action: ({

                let nmo = ToDoItem(context: self.managedObjectContext)

                nmo.id = UUID()
                nmo.title = self.updatedTitle
                nmo.firstName = self.updatedFirstName
                nmo.lastName = self.updatedLastName
                nmo.createdAt = Date()

                do {
                    try self.managedObjectContext.save()
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }

                self.updatedTitle = ""
                self.updatedFirstName = ""
                self.updatedLastName = ""
                self.updatedDateString = ""

                self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()

            })) {
                Text("Save")
            }
            .padding()
        }
        .padding(10)
        Spacer()
    }
}
}
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: also got this. did you figured it out?

Comment: This seems to be fixed in Xcode 11.1 (11A1027).